# Error(11,15): PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, ora-04044

I am trying to get data from 4 tables FACTS_CDPM, PRODUCT, CUSTOMER, DATE into CUST_ALLOC table, 
when I just run the select query, i get the result, but when I put it inside a procedure and do an insert into with the select statement as below, I get an error "Error(11,15): PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here"

Please can somebody help as to why this is happening?

Thank you!

```
INSERT INTO CUST_ALLOC
(PART_ID,
      CUSTOMER,
      MONTH,
      QTY_ALLOCATED
        )    
    SELECT P.PROD_ID,
       C.PURCHASING,
       D.MONTH_ID,
       SUM(X.QTY)
FROM FACTS_CDPM X INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PROD_NUM=X.PROD_NUM 
                    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON X.CUST_NUM=C.CUST_NUM 
                    INNER JOIN DATE D ON X.DATE_NUM=D.DATE_NUM
WHERE MEASURE_NUM=18
GROUP BY P.PROD_ID,C.PURCHASING,D.MONTH_ID;
```

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire procedure?

Comment: My first suspicion would be `MEASURE_NUM` - is it a column in one of those tables? I'd put an alias on it.

Comment: If the procedure is called "P" you might have a naming conflict with the alias for PRODUCT. I'd be very wary of having a table called DATE too.

Answer (score 5):

`DATE` is a reserved keyword in Oracle. Your procedure shouldn't even compile if it contained the insert statement you posted. If you're going to use DATE for a table name, put it in quotes:

```
INNER JOIN "DATE" ON X.DATE_NUM="DATE".DATE_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

issue must have been with synonym and grant provided to the **CUST_ALLOC** table. I tried resolving this by removing the synonym and grant already provided and tried creating a new one with care. It worked!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).